# Grub Autostart with timeout

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

On Ubuntu 10.4 LTS I want Grub to start the default OS after 5 Seconds. I'd like to see the output of the startup scripts.

Currently grub wait forever until I hit return and the output of the startup scripts isn't visible. Can someone tell me how I have to configure `/etc/default/grub` or any other setups?

I tried to play with `GRUB_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_DEFAULT` and did a `sudo update-grub` afterwards, but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
# GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the results of init scripts, remove the `quiet` option like this  :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"
```

To correct the forever wait, try to edit the file in `/etc/grub.d/00_header` and replace

```
if [ ${recordfail} = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=${GRUB_TIMEOUT}
fi
```

with

```
set timeout=${GRUB_TIMEOUT}
```

then launch `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do get the output of the init scripts, but grub is still not starting the first OS automatically.